# Using sum aggregate with CoreData

Tags: core-data, sum, swift2

I try to use Sum aggregate function on a property but i get a strange error that i'm unable to correct :

`2015-12-13 11:32:29.280 YoBuM[634:42509] -[NSDecimalNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000025ce0
2015-12-13 11:32:29.281 YoBuM[634:42509] -[NSDecimalNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000025ce0
2015-12-13 11:32:29.286 YoBuM[634:42509] (
0   CoreFoundation
    0x00007fff8a8e0ae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib
    0x00007fff97b6473c objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation
    0x00007fff8a8e3b9d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation
    0x00007fff8a81c601 ___forwarding___ + 1009
4   CoreFoundation
    0x00007fff8a81c188 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation
    0x00007fff9796cff6 +[_NSPredicateUtilities _getCommonTypeFor:] + 76
6   Foundation
    0x00007fff9796d30a +[_NSPredicateUtilities sum:] + 144
7   Foundation
    0x00007fff977d2cff -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 1094 ...`

My code is :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Operation)
class Operation: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var amount: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var days: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var designation: String?
    @NSManaged var isDebit: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var element: Element?

    class func tests(appDel: AppDelegate, forElement: Element) -> (q1: Double, q2: Double, q3: Double, q4: Double) {
        let moc = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Operation")

        let expressionDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
        expressionDesc.name = "sumOfAmount"
        let amountExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")
        expressionDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [amountExpr])
        expressionDesc.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType
        request.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDesc]
        request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        let elementPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "element = %@", forElement)
        let creditPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDebit = %@", true)

        let year = (forElement.budget as! Budget).year!.integerValue
        var minDate = Utils.getDate("01/01/\(year)")
        var maxDate = Utils.getDate("04/01/\(year)")
        let datesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", minDate, maxDate)
        let predicates = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [elementPredicate, creditPredicate, datesPredicate])
        request.predicate = predicates

        do {
            //error is here when some entities are found for the given predicates
            let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(request)

            // ...
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Oops: \(error).")
        }
        //return (q1, q2, q3, q4)
    }
}
```

I don't know why there's a count selector in the error trace.
Did i choose the "good" approach here for summing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this should be a class method. You are fetching arbitrary `Operation` instances, so there is no good argument why this should be called in the context of one particular instance.

Second, I think this can be simplified greatly as follows: fetch all operations with the given constraints, then:

```
let q1Sum = (operations as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount").doubleValue
```

or, more "swiftly":

```
let q1Sum = operations.map { $0.amount.doubleValue }.reduce(0, combine: +)
```

There is no good discernible reason for going into `NSExpression` complexities and for using `NSDictionaryResultType`, unless you are getting performance issues, which would be highly unlikely.

Comment: ok, thanks for your interest.
But i don't understand the origin of `operations`.
If i comment all lines concerning NSExpression, `results` will contains an array of `Operation` which i don't know how to aggregate. I should miss something obvious...

Comment: You would fetch `operations` with the appropriate predicate filters. The computation of the sum is shown in my answer.

Comment: Sorry my poor knowledges on the subject, i’m beginning with Swift so i don’t understand very well ;)

i removed all about `NSExpressions` and changed the fetch request like this :   `let q1Sum = results.valuesForKeyPath() //-> Value of type '[Operation]' has no member 'valuesForKeyPath’`.  In other words, how i get  this `Operations` variable/member allowing me to call valuesForKeyPath(string) ?

Comment: It's `valueForKeyPath` not `valuesForKeyPath`.

Comment: You might need to cast to NSArray: `(results as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount")`. I edited my answer to also give a more Swift-like syntax.

Comment: Something is wrong with my predicates and i'm going look at forward, but the sum works fine. Thanks a lot for all these explanations.